# how to decode h.264 slice mode stream with type-9 NALs on iOS

Tags: ios, video, h.264

The input raw bitstream has type 9 NALs (AU delimiter).

There are multiple NALs of type 5 or 1 between NAL type 9. for ex: {NAL-9, NAL-5, NAL-5, NAL-9, NAL-1, NAL-1, NAL-9, NAL-1, NAL-1 ....}. I believe the encoder used slice mode (raw stream is from windows h.264 encoder which has slice mode enabled via low latency flag).

How do i feed such stream to iOS?

My guess: put all NALs between two NAL-9 into one buffer, removed NAL-9, and send those buffers to HW decoder.

In my example, buffers going to decoder will look like : {NAL-5, NAL-5}, {NAL-1, NAL-1}, {NAL-1, NAL-1}. The output result shows that decode happens but with lot of green artifacts which makes me think that there is something missing in the above approach.

Comment: I was stitching at a wrong place in the program. After some corrections, I passed stitched buffer (with start code replaced by NAL sizes for all IDRs between two NAL-9s) to CMBlockBufferCreateWithMemoryBlock() API. Did the same for all P Slices between two NAL-9s and that seems to be working.

Comment: size passed to CMSampleBufferCreate() is the total size of all slices in the buffer and sample count is set to 1